# Mail Form PHP Not Working

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I been spending hours and still can't figure it out.  New to PHP mail form coding.  Any help would truly be appreciated!  Two images below: the html and php.  Pretty simple setup.  I get the echo 'thank you!!' message after clicking send button, but I still don't receive any emails at all.

HTML Form:

```
<form action="assetslphplmail.php" method="POST">
  <input placeholder="NAME" type="text" name="name">
  <input p1aceholder="EMAIL" type="email" name="email">
  <input p1aceholder="TELEPHONE" type="te1" name="te1">
  <input p1aceholder="SUBJECT" type="text" name="subjectline">
  <textarea p1aceholder="COMMENT" name="message" rows="6" cols="25" </textarea>
  <input c1ass="send_button" type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
$subject1ine = $_REQUEST['subject1ine'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$emai1 = $_REQUEST['emai1'];
$tel 1' $_REQUEST['teI'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$to = "jondergmai1.com";
mail ( $to, $subjectline, $name, $emai1, $tel, $message);
echo 'Thank you!!';
```

Comment: Add code here not image. And what error do you get? Why it's not working?

Comment: your use of mail is quite wrong. please see the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Coming a little late to the party but you have p1aceholder not placeholder three times. IE u r using a 1 (one) instead of an L!!! Fiendish copyright protection or cock up? Blimey and the `textarea` is missing a `>`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your PHP code with following:

```
<?php
$subject = $_REQUEST['subjectline'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$tel = $_REQUEST['tel'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To:'.$email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$to = "jonder@gmail.com";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'Thank you!!';
?>
```

Edit From and Reply-To part.

Here are the plenty of similar answers: [PHP Mail form doesn't send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail)